# Repairing damage on the floor

Tags: floor

I dropped a beer glass and got a damage on the floor around 2.5 cm long. I am not sure about the material on the floor because the damage looks more like that something is peeling off. If it had been marble, then there would have been a one straight crack. Maybe its vinyl?

The following question is how to repair this? Is there any repair set available to hide this? I have seen a couple of them on amazon but dont know which one would be the right one. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks like old linoleum, do you know the age of the flooring? I ask because pre 70's asbestos was used in some brands.

Comment: The std repair would be to cut out the damaged area and replace it with a piece of the same top layer. It looks like some crushable material might have been used under the top layer. It appears that this is squares so unless it is a very recent installation it would be vinyl rather than linoleum. https://www.hunker.com/13411690/how-to-tell-if-you-have-vinyl-or-linoleum

Comment: Why did you remove your photos? The question isn't very valuable without them. You should either restore the photos and resolve the question or delete it.

Comment: i tried to delete this post, but failed to do so. I deleted the pics because of personal and unavoidable reasons.. more related to my insurance company and I dont want them to see that I have tried to repair the floor myself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like vinyl tile to me (VCT), judging by the straight lines in the upper photo. You're not going to be able to repair that without replacing the tile, and you won't be able to match tile that old very well. This is especially true if it's sheet vinyl.

I'd try gently tapping it flat with a hammer, and re-wax the floor to fill it a bit. Any other filler will show worse than the damage itself.

Comment: how do you re-wax? Can you please suggest a link what I can follow?